# Is it possible to cache a broken image?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to ensure that the browser caches invalid/broken "images" such that when there is a re-fetch, the loading time is immediate.

Below are two scenarios I'm particularly interested in.

1) The first is where I try to load an image from a url which contains a different type of resource (e.g. in this case `text/html`). The status of the request is `200` but the resource is **not an image**.

2) The second is where I try to load an image which simply doesn't exist. The status of the request is `404`.

```
// takes ~500ms to load
const urlText = "https://goodreads.com"
const brokenTextImage = new Image();
brokenTextImage.src = urlText;

// takes ~500ms to load
const url404 = "https://broken.com/${gres.psm}.png"
const broken404Image = new Image();
broken404Image.src = url404; 

// looking to cache - should take ~0ms to load
const cachedTextImage = new Image();
cachedBrokenTextImage.src = urlText; 

// looking to cache - should take ~0ms to load
const cached404Image = new Image();
cached404Image.src = url404;
```

In both cases, I would like to reduce the loading times to ~0ms, such as you might expect from the caching mechanism of valid image urls. Is this possible?

---

See the image here for an example of this failed caching in action. You can see a number fetches for the 404 image, as well as the goodreads "image," and an example of a successful image sourced from 'disk cache'

Image response times:

[image: Image response times]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  If the question is "How do I cache my 404 image," the same way you cache all the others.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would expect the browser to automatically cache the resource, just like valid image urls, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I'll add an image to OP to clarify

Comment: Oh, so you're trying to cache a resource that doesn't exist?  I'm not sure there's a way to do that; you have to make a trip to the server to identify the 404.

Comment: I think most of time comes from the server processing the request. Upgrade the server to http/2 and use server push

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers come with something called service worker -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

With the service worker up and running you can register a fetch event -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent

With this you have full control of how resources are cached.
Also note, the fetch event effects all resource loading, include HTML / Ajax & of course fetch.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but is there a way to do this without service workers? Unfortunately I can't introduce them in my current env just for this use case. Might a blob pre-fetch work?

Comment: The only other way I can think of is use a proxy server and get that to cache the 404's..   Or if you have access to the server that's generating the 404's, get that to push out a long expiry..