# How to conditionally render an image in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Imagine that I want to create a component to render an image. If the image resource is valid, I should render it into a div via css `background-image`. Otherwise I should render it as a standard `<img>` with an alt tag.

So we get something like this:

```
const ImageComponent = ({src}) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [renderFallback, setRenderFallback] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onsuccess = () => {
      setLoaded(true);
      setRenderFallback(false);
    }
    image.onerror = () => {
      setLoaded(true);
      setRenderFallback(true);
    }
    image.src = src;

    return () => {
      // clean up listeners
      image.onsuccess = undefined;
      image.onerror = undefined;
    }
  }, [src]);

  if (!loaded) { return null; }

  return renderFallback ?
    <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${src})`}}/> :
    <img src={src} alt="my alt"/>;
}
```

Here, we first kick off a fetch for the image via plain javascript (within useEffect). If it's valid, the resource is cached (by the browser), and the rendering of the subsequent `<div>` is instantaneous.

However, if the resource is not valid, then there is no caching mechanism in place (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621406/is-it-possible-to-cache-a-broken-image) for more details). And so when we render the new `<img>` element at the end of the Component, it kicks off a brand new request to fetch that image (despite deducing that it's broken already).

So, to avoid this duplicate fetching, a possible solution would be to render the already-initialized `image` element, rather than a new react element to represent that image.

Is this possible?

---

**Feedback from comments**

- An invalid image is one that returns a *status of 404*, or points to a resource that's *not actually an image* (e.g. `https://goodreads.com`)
- I would like to display the browser's default 'broken image' in cases where it's broken. This can't be done via `background-image` css, so I need to rely on a standard `<img>` element. As I've already determined that the image is broken (in useEffect), I'd like to avoid a new fetch when I'm rendering the broken `<img>` in React.

Hope that clarifies things!

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit what you call an invalid image? Is this an image that you want to upload?

Comment: User `React.memo()` to avoid unwanted re render of components. Refer the link for more details https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-166-reactmemo-for-functional-components-rendering-control

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do here, The 404 will still take time.  If your saying this 404 is always going to be invalid and you want to cache it that way.  Then what you could do is use localeStorage to flag this url as invalid..

Comment: @t3__rry This is related to the other question I linked. An invalid image would be one that points to a _non-image resource_ (e.g. `https://goodreads.com`), or one that returns a status of 404

Comment: I believe I understand what your after,  your React code looks like it's not far off, your not passing props but src, so that doesn't make sense but apart from that it looks like with a bit of modification you could get this do what your after using Session/LocaleStorage, with options to even put in custom expiry dates etc.  If  you could knock up a snippet, I could alter it.

Answer (score 2):

My definition of valid is: the image has been loaded and it has both a width and a height greater than zero.

Now there are two ways you check if an image is valid:

- Assume the image is not valid, try loading the image, check if it is valid, then render the image tag.
- Assume the image is valid, render the `img` tag, then check if the image is valid.

The following code will first assume that the image **is not valid**.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const ImageComponent = ({src}) => {
    const container = useRef(null);
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        container.current.innerHTML = '';

        const image = new Image();

        const checkValid = () => {
            if (image.complete && image.naturalWidth > 0 && image.naturalHeight > 0) {
                setValid(true);
                container.current.appendChild(image);
            }
        }

        image.onload = checkValid;
        image.src = src;
    }, [src]);

    return (
        <div>
          <div ref={container} />
          {!valid && <div>Image not valid</div>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Usage:

```
<ImageComponent src="IMAGE_URL" />
```

The following code will first assume that the image **is valid**.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

const ImageComponent = ({src}) => {
    const image = useRef(null);
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(true);

    const checkValid = () => {
        if (!image.current.complete || image.current.naturalWidth < 1 || image.current.naturalHeight < 1) setValid(false);
    }

    if (valid) {
        return (
            <img
                src={src}
                onLoad={checkValid}
                onError={() => setValid(false)}
                ref={image} 
            />
        );
    }

    return <div>Image not valid</div>;
};
```

Usage:

```
<ImageComponent src="IMAGE_URL" />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks or your answer. The situation is actually the opposite. If the image is valid, show the div. Otherwise, the `<img>`

Comment: Added alternative code that will first check image validity and then render it. A container element is required in order to append the image element.